# Why i am not able to compare an array of pointer and an array?

Tags: c++

I am getting error :  ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
Can anyone please help me in resolving this error ???
Here is my code......

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    char *ptr[4] = {"books","television","computer","sports"};
    char str[10];
    cout << "Enter your favourite liesure pursuit : ";
    cin >> str;
    for(int a=0;a<4;a++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(str,ptr[a]))
        {
            cout << "Your favourite pursuit is available here \n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n Yopr favourite pursuit isn't available here \n";
        }
        getch();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The answer can be easy googled.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) is typed as `const char*` because modifying them leads to undefined behaviour.

As such, you need those `const`, like this:

```cpp
const *ptr[] = { ... };
```

Also consider using `std::vector` and `std::string` since this is C++. When you use C++ instead of *fancy C* you get code like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  // Easily compose an extensible list of categories
  std::vector<std::string> categories = { "books", "television", "computers", "sports" };

  std::string input; // Use a string for input
  std::cin >> input; // No more buffer overflows!

  // Find an entry in the list
  if (std::find(categories.begin(), categories.end(), input) != categories.end()) {
    std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Not Found" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```